# Drawing a straight line drag and drop in class Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing

How can I draw a straight line on a drag and drop, that there was only one line and moved around?

My code:

```
panelPaint.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    point1 = e.getPoint();
                }
            });
            panelPaint.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    point2 = e.getPoint();

                    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(point1, point2));

                    panelPaint.repaint();
                }
            });
```

Current effect:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWFCE.png]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are drawing to a BufferedImage or something. You should not be doing painting using a Graphics object in the mouse event.

Instead you should be doing custom painting on a panel and override the `paintCompnent(...)` method. Your `paintComponent()` method should look like:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Grapahics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // custom painting here
    g.drawLine(...);

}
```

The first statement will clear the background. The next statement will draw the line between your starting/ending points.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for more information and examples. The example will dynamically draw a Rectangle as you drag the mouse, but the concept is the same for a single line.

Comment: I wrote paint. On the panel are other elements. I can`t cleaner. More code: http://pastebin.com/14Bqmzx7

Comment: @Q.One, Of course you can clear the panel. You need to then repaint all the other components as well as the line. Look at the example in the link provided!!! I'm not going to read your code. I've given you working code that shows how to do custom painting. Take the time to test the code, understand how it works and then modify your code. We are not here to write/debug your code.